# Mean deviation of Binomial distribution has square root growth

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics

Let $N, N_1, N_2 \geq 1$ be natural numbers s.t. $N = N_1 + N_2$, furthermore let $c$ be a positive real number. Let $M$ be binomially distributed with parameters $\lfloor cN \rfloor$ and $N_1 / N$.

I want to show that
$$\mathbb{E}[|M-\lfloor cN_1 \rfloor|] = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N}).$$

I have tried splitting up the expectation to remove the absolute values and then bounding the sums s.t. I can apply the binomial theorem, but this just leads to $\mathcal{O}(N)$ which is obvious anyway.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearer to me in standard notations.  The OP's $M$ is binomial with parameters $p=N_1/N$ and $n=c\lfloor N \rfloor$, and the OP wants a bound on $A = E|M-c\lfloor N_1 \rfloor|$.  Let $\Delta = |c\lfloor N_1 \rfloor - np|.$  Then $$ \left|A - E | M-np| \right| \le \Delta.$$  By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $E|M-np| \le \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}\,(M)} < \sqrt{np}.$  Hence, finally, $$ A \le \Delta + \sqrt{np}.$$

Which, I think, is $\mathcal O (\sqrt N)$ as the OP wanted, even though he did not define  a limiting regime defining the big Oh notation.